# How to extract substrings in r

Tags: r, substring, text-extraction

Say I have a string:

```
{"id":"35","value":"0.2"},{"id":"1462","value":"0.2"},
{"id":"1109","value":"0.2"},{"id":"220","value":"0.2"},
{"id":"211","value":"0.1"}
```

I need to extract substrings in each `{}`

Than create columns with an id in the header and a number corresponding to the id like:

```
35  1462 1109 220 211
----------
0.2  0.2 0.2  0.2 0.1
```

Comment: Easy, use a JSON parser, and then iterate over your JSON content to generate the output you want.  This is _not_ a job for `sub`, or any other R regex function.

Comment: `s <- '{"id":"35","value":"0.2"},{"id":"1462","value":"0.2"},
{"id":"1109","value":"0.2"},{"id":"220","value":"0.2"},
{"id":"211","value":"0.1"}'; 
L <- readLines(textConnection(gsub("\\},", "}\n", s)));
L <- L[L != ""];
ndjson::flatten(L)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `jsonlite` after `paste`ing `[`, `]` at the start and end respectively

```
d1 <- jsonlite::fromJSON(paste0('[', str1, ']'))
```

It will be a 2 column dataset which can be converted to 4 column by

```
setNames(as.data.frame.list(d1$value), d1$id)
#   35 1462 1109 220 211
#1 0.2  0.2  0.2 0.2 0.1
```

---

Suppose, we have multiple strings, then collapse those strings to a single one and apply the `fromJSON`

```
str2 <- c(str1, str1)
d1 <- jsonlite::fromJSON(paste0("[", paste(str2, collapse=",\n"), "]"))
```

#### data

```
str1 <- '{"id":"35","value":"0.2"},{"id":"1462","value":"0.2"},{"id":"1109","value":"0.2"},{"id":"220","value":"0.2"},{"id":"211","value":"0.1"}'
```

Comment: I have one more question, if you don't mind. 
How to apply this to multiple strings? I'm thinking on creating a loop. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: @NikitaPronin  Please check the updated post